How to i go about pitching a share ware concept to explore talent and investments?
I have years of work laying out an Epic concept now primed for crypto gaming. Originally written to be a illustrated novel, I would like to use the concept to learning all I can about blockchain communities as i participate in the construct. I have a vast Archive of work value I would like to inject into crypto and was told this was the place to do it.
I'll share more as applicable.

I'd suggest to look for blockchain hackatons for gaming. They are usually a good place for networking and showing your work. They are usually organized by investors looking for the next thing.
